# Undefined reference in debug, but OK in release

Tags: c++

I've encountered a weird problem. My code works perfectly in *Release* build, but fails to compile in *Debug*. Quite the opposite to the problems one usually have. :)

in *.h file I have a constant:

```
class OBDenrChrg : public OBChargeModel
{
public:
  bool ComputeCharges(OBMol &mol);
// blah-blah-blah
private:
  static const float c = 0.05;
};
```

in *.cpp file I use this constant:

```
bool OBDenrChrg::ComputeCharges(OBMol &mol)
{
// blah-blah-blah
  Eigen::VectorXf a0 = L*EN*c;
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> A = L*HRD*c + I;
// blah-blah-blah
}
```

The built is controlled by cmake. The *Release* target builds and works well. The *Debug* says:

```
CMakeFiles/plugin_charges.dir/charges/denr.o: 
In function `OpenBabel::OBDenrChrg::ComputeCharges(OpenBabel::OBMol&)':
/home/titov/openbabel-2.3.2/src/charges/denr.cpp:181: undefined reference to `OpenBabel::OBDenrChrg::c'
/home/titov/openbabel-2.3.2/src/charges/denr.cpp:182: undefined reference to `OpenBabel::OBDenrChrg::c'
```

I have no **#ifdef DEBUG** or similar switches in these files.

Any ideas on how to fix the problem and what may cause it?

**Edit:**

Thanks everyone for the help. 
The problem was in the abscence of `c`'s **definition**, since **declaration** of a `static` member inside of `class`' **definition** does not **define** the `static` member. What a mess...

Comment: My guess? The release build optimizes out the use of the variable (i.e. the compiler replaces all instances of `c` with its value) so it's actually not referenced anywhere in the generated code. The debug build does not do that optimization, and so you need a *definition* of the variable. There are plenty of duplicates all over the Internet on how to define a `static` member variables, including quite a few here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Where have you put the definition of `OBDenrChrg::c`? (I suspect an ODR violation which wouldn't _require_ a diagnostic.)